# ExoPlayer слишком большая высота

Tags: android

Пытаюсь кастомизировать ExoPlayer. Получилось вот так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout
        android:id="@id/exo_content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:resize_mode="fill">

        <View
            android:id="@id/exo_shutter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/exo_artwork"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SubtitleView
            android:id="@id/exo_subtitles"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@id/exo_controller_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/exo_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</merge>
```

Во фрагменте у самого SimpleExoPlayerView такие параметры

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/player"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:show_timeout="0"></com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView>
```

В приложении почему-то внизу остается свободное место после полосы со временем. Не могу понять почему. Почему SimpleExoPlayerView в высоту не подстраивается начиная от кнопок до полосы со временем, а еще остается место снизу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]